# Electrode placement in ECG circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, ecg

[image]

Source: https://digital.wpi.edu/downloads/ns064789m?locale=zh

Could someone tell where exactly the V1-V6 electrode inputs should be attached to in this circuit?

Comment: Where is the legend for this circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the print you posted, this is just an initial reference mentioned by the authors. Following this circuit, on the same page, you can see:

[image]

the circuit provides a single lead (the differential reading of LA and RA) and the average potential to the RL circuit.

> where exactly the V1-V6 electrode inputs should be attached to in this circuit?

They are not connected to this circuit, which is just "an initial reference".