# Battery placement in ECG circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, circuit-design, power-electronics, ecg

[image]

Could someone tell me how to connect this circuit to power source?

Shouldn't I attach battery's positive poles to all the +Vs and negative to -Vs?

Why are the -Vs (4th legs) grounded?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electrode placement in ECG circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671593/electrode-placement-in-ecg-circuit)

Comment: You have been told that this is an "initial reference" based on the information you provided.

Comment: Nika Abashidze - Hi, Please remember to include the [required reference link](/help/referencing) for the content which you copy into your question. After a previous reminder you correctly included those links in earlier questions, thanks, but you didn't do it here. Please [edit] your question to add the source of that schematic which you copied. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question @SolarMike. Same circuit, but different question. Which is what we ask questioners to do to avoid multiple question in a single post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called “single supply” operation. You can notice the midpoint bias labeled 1/2 Vs that is sometimes called a virtual ground. The method allows the split supply op-amps to be used on a single battery.

Some op-amps do not perform well in this configuration. Others are specifically designed for this kind of application.